# Leaflet Temporal animation of marker clusters

Tags: javascript, leaflet, animation, spatio-temporal-data

I recently have applied the markercluster leaflet plug-in to my map and I was wondering if something like leaflet.timeline would be compatible with cluster visualization?

if not is there any other temporal animation plug in that may work with the marker cluster within leaflet?